# What's the meaning of the word "pastoral" in this context?

Tags: meaning

Iford Manor has been described as one of the most stunning concert venues in the West Country.  Throughout high summer, Iford Arts stages an internationally renowned festival in a breathtakingly beautiful **pastoral** setting. Operatic performances are staged in-the-round in the intimate surroundings of the Italianate Cloister, which could not be more perfect in terms of scale and style. While the classical backdrop could hardly be more fitting, the real delight for our audiences is that, as the sky turns purple overhead, the first stars appear and the first heady notes resound across the countryside, no-one is seated less than twenty feet from the performers. The opportunity for a relaxing pre-show picnic in our tranquil gardens overlooking the meandering River Frome will complete an already magical experience.

I have found two meanings of this word, but it seems to me that neither of them fits.

1) Of or pertaining to shepherds; hence, relating to rural life and scenes; as, a pastoral life (Source: en.wiktionary.org)

(especially of land or a farm) used for or related to the keeping or grazing of sheep or cattle (Source: Google Translate)

2) Relating to the care of souls, or to the pastor of a church (Source: en.wiktionary.org)

(in the Christian Church) concerning or appropriate to the giving of spiritual guidance (Source: Google Translate)

Edit: if someone is able to answer this question, I would like to get a synonym for "pastoral". Thanks in advance.

Comment: How come you don't think the first one doesn't fit? _... breathtakingly rural ..._ means roughly the same, but _pastoral_ doesn't have some of the negative connotations _rural_ does.

Comment: If you need persuading of the meaning, have a look at this ---> https://goo.gl/esi5pU

Comment: Since you requested it, [*bucolic*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/bucolic) is a synonym for *pastoral.*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Pastoral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pastoral#Pastoral_literature) is also a literary tradition of sentimentally idealizing a rustic, rural existence. (Its origins stretch all the way back to classical antiquity, the *Idylls* of Theocritus and the *Eclogues* of Virgil, but bits of it are found in *As You Like It,* *Don Quixote,* Milton’s “Lycidas,” and even—mockingly—in the Savoy Operas of Gilbert and Sullivan. Classical names go with the territory: shepherds named Strephon, Lycidas, Corin, Sylvius, etc., and shepherdesses Chloe, Phyllis, Amaryllis, etc. Dresden used rather to specialize in china figurines of these types.) So when an advertising brochure boasts “a breathtakingly beautiful pastoral setting,” it means that the setting is an instance of rural scenery that actually lives up to our fondest imaginings of green pastures, limpid streams, bosky hillsides, etc.

Comment: This is getting suspiciously close to lit crit. But I'm fond of the word, and this obviously beats the clinical old dictionaries.

Comment: In music the word becomes *pastorale* - e.g. Beethoven's third symphony.

Comment: @WS2, I think it's his 6th, in F, Op. 68; and I think the extra "e" shows up only when that piece is being named in German, French, or Italian. My Naxos CD, labeled in English, omits it.

Comment: @BrianDonovan Gosh. You are right - it is his sixth. Don't tell my wife I got it wrong - because we had it for our wedding 44 years ago - the organist was a friend of ours. As for *pastorale*, it is in the OED under that spelling, and denotes two uses in that form - one in music, and the other in dance.

Answer (score 2):

*Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* (2003) includes this shepherd-free definition of *pastoral*:

> pleasingly peaceful and innocent: IDYLLIC

And this one:

> of or relating to the countryside : not urban

And here's the *Eleventh Collegiate*'s relevant definition of *idyllic*:

> pleasing or picturesque in natural simplicity

Another one-word adjective option (besides *idyllic*) is *arcadian*, which the *Eleventh Collegiate* defines as follows:

> idyllically pastoral; *esp* : idyllically innocent, simple, or untroubled